# Concatenation of 2 strings in reverse

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I have 2 strings:

`str1 = 12345`

`str2 = abcde`

As a result I need to have the following:

`5a4b3c2d1e`

How is it possible to do?

Comment: If you know how to reverse a string, and you know how to concatenate strings, it should be a sinple matter to combine them.

Comment: you want to interleave the strings

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using map and zip, but you have to convert the int to a string as well.

```py
str1 = 12345
str2 = "abcde"
foo = ''.join(map(''.join, zip(str(str1)[::-1], str2)))
print(foo)

5a4b3c2d1e
```

[::-1] reverses the string that was an int

zip() breaks the two strings into pairs (list of tuples)

```
[('5', 'a'), ('4', 'b'), ('3', 'c'), ('2', 'd'), ('1', 'e')]
```

first .join makes it into a list

```
['5a', '4b', '3c', '2d', '1e']
```

second .join converts list to string

```
5a4b3c2d1e
```